# How to create a dataframe on the basis of duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a DataFrame, somethings like this:

```py
df=pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4],"b":[5,4,8,9,2,3,4,1,9,5,6,7,8,6,1,8]})
printf(df)
'''
    a  b
0   1  5
1   1  4
2   1  8
3   1  9
4   2  2
5   2  3
6   2  4
7   2  1
8   3  9
9   3  5
10  3  6
11  3  7
12  4  8
13  4  6
14  4  1
15  4  8
'''
```

And now I want to create a new DataFrame on the basis of that repeating value of "a" and values of "b", which would look like this:

```
   1  2  3  4
0  5  2  9  8
1  4  3  5  6
2  8  4  6  1
3  9  1  7  8
```

I had tried direct approach like

```py
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(["a"]))
```

But it is giving me two column

```
    0   1
0   1   a b 0 1 5 1 1 4 2 1 8 3 1 9
1   2   a b 4 2 2 5 2 3 6 2 4 7 2 1
2   3   a b 8 3 9 9 3 5 10 3 6 11 3 7
3   4   a b 12 4 8 13 4 6 14 4 1 15 4 8
```

Comment: Are the groups going the have the same size always?

Comment: @DaniMesejo It would be better if it is solved by assuming not but most of the time they will be same.

Comment: The problem is that you are going to have nan if they have different sizes

Comment: Yeah! That will be fine...

Answer (score 1):

`cumcount()` each group of a and transpose using `pivot()`

```
(df.assign(idx=df.groupby('a').cumcount())
   .pivot(index='idx', columns='a', values='b')
).reset_index(drop=True)
```

The output looks like this:

```
a   1   2   3   4
0   5   2   9   8
1   4   3   5   6
2   8   4   6   1
3   9   1   7   8
```

If you may be confused about how it works, you can separate each function like

```
df1 = df.assing(idx=df.groupby("a").cumcount())
df2 = df1.pivot(index='idx', columns='a', values='b').reset_index(drop=True)
```

It returns the same result